# Mvc routing and numeric view names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an area with a History folder that I have views for each year in.  The views are called for example Year2010, Year2011 etc and are just used to display historical data.  I tried to call them simply 2010, 2011 but it seems to be against naming conventions.  Instead of having a route History/Year2010 I would like to be able to just use History/2010, is this possible and if so how?

Comment: I believe this would require you to have an action method named `2010`, which is a violation of the C# spec on method names.  Perhaps you could have your `Index` action take the year as an Id parameter, then use the overload of `View()` to specify the view name.  Sounds like a bad idea to me, but you could try it.

Comment: Not completely sure on this, but have you tried: [ActionName("2010")]
public ActionResult Year2010()

Comment: The comment above was the answer I was looking for, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom route for the History pages, so that the action is defaulted and the year is passed in as a parameter.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "History",
    "History/{year}",
    new { controller = "History", action = "Display", year = DateTime.Today.Year }
);
```

Then, in your controller, check the passed in year and display the correct view:

```
public ActionResult Display(int year)
{
    switch (year)
    {
        case 2010:
            return View("Year2010");
        case 2011:
            return View("Year2011");
    }
    return View();
}
```